# How to confirm prompt value and then add 1 to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var button = (".button");
var password = "rip peter";
var jimmyCount = 0;
var nickCount = 0;  

$( ".button" ).click(function() {
    var userAnswer = prompt("Who would win in a fight\n\nJimmy or Nick?", "");
    console.log(userAnswer);
});

    // Compare

var compare = function(userAnswer, password) {
    if (userAnswer != password) {
        alert("Nope");
    }
    else {
        $("#jimmyMinus").click(function() { jimmyCount -= 1});
        $("#jimmyPlus").click(function() { jimmyCount += 1});
        $("#nickMinus").click(function() { nickCount -= 1});
        $("#nickPlus").click(function() { nickCount += 1});
    }
}
```

I'm trying to build a counter that needs a 'password' to allow a user to +1 or -1 to a score.. However whilst the prompt works, and stores the value it isn't compared nor added/subtracted..

Additionally, I'd like to then add this number to the html somewhere but don't know how to :s

Comment: Is it on the same browser, or different one?

Comment: you need to call the `compare()` function once you get the userAnswer using prompt only then will the value be compared to the password.

Comment: I removed some lines from your Q because asking for links gets you closed as off-topic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not executing the `compare()` function:

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
  var userAnswer = prompt("Who would win in a fight\n\nJimmy or Nick?", "");
  console.log(userAnswer);
  compare(userAnswer);
});
```

Also, throw the above handler, after the function has been declared.

```js
var button = (".button");
var password = "rip peter";
var jimmyCount = 0;
var nickCount = 0;  

// Compare

var compare = function(userAnswer) {
  if (userAnswer != password) {
    alert("Nope");
  }
  else {
    $("#jimmyMinus").click(function() { jimmyCount -= 1});
    $("#jimmyPlus").click(function() { jimmyCount += 1});
    $("#nickMinus").click(function() { nickCount -= 1});
    $("#nickPlus").click(function() { nickCount += 1});
  }
}

$( ".button" ).click(function() {
  var userAnswer = prompt("Who would win in a fight\n\nJimmy or Nick?", "");
  console.log(userAnswer);
  compare(userAnswer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="button">Click Me</span>
```

And remove the second parameter of `password` from the function.